# How to check whether char exists in string using strstr() function in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

This must be a simple problem about char data type and pointers.

```
void main() {

    const char* a;
    char character = 65;
    a = &character;

    printf("%c \n", character); // PRINTS 'A' AS EXPECTED

    if (strstr("ABC", a)) { 
        printf("found \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("not found\n"); // goes into else
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't go into first if statement.

Comment: `a` is not a string. A string in C is a NUL terminated sequence of characters.

Comment: You meant to use strchr didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to null terminate the `a` string so that it's a proper C string before calling strstr:

Any of the following:

```
if (strstr("ABC", "A"))
{
    // found
}
```

Or

```
char a[2] = {'A', '\0'};
if (strstr("ABC", a))
{
    // found
}
```

Or

```
const char* a = "A";
if (strstr("ABC", a))
{
    // found
}
```

Comment: or `if (strstr("ABC", (char [2]){a}))`.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not a string. It is because strings in C need to be null terminated. By null terminated, I mean it's last element should be 0. It's so that when you pass strings to functions, then he functions can know when the string ends. The null terminating 0 is used to mark the end of a string.

You need to do:

```
char *a;
char character[2];
character[0] = 'A'; //Don't use 65. ASCII isn't the only encoding
character[1] = '\0';
a = character; //a is useless, you can pass character directly
```

Now, pass it: strstr("ABC", a)`. The above method is very bad, don't use it. Do one of these in practice:

```
char a[2] = "A"; //This will null terminate for you
//OR
const char *a = "A";
//OR
char a[2] = {'A', '\0'};
```

Using any one of these declarations, `strstr` should work.